# roscore on windows

Tags: roscore, windows

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I want to run roscore in Windows. Otherwise, I need one more system.
What do I do first? I don't mind that roscore is working without logging.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9279/roscore-on-windows/) by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 71 on 2011-03-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

roscore itself won't work as it uses roslaunch, which hasn't been ported to work with Windows processes.

You can, however, run rosmaster manually, which is the heart of roscore.  You'll have to follow the instructions for [ROS Python on Windows](http://www.ros.org/wiki/cturtle/Installation/Windows) (same link that makokal pointed to).

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-03-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) on 2011-03-07**:
Please select the answer you prefer by clicking the checkmark next to the answer.  That will allow this question to be shown as "answered"

**Comment by [hughie](https://answers.ros.org/users/232/hughie/) on 2011-03-06**:
Thank you for answer.